# Error: "Couldn't resolve host 'magento-community'" when installing a Extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect, third-party-module

I cannot install any Extensions on magento. I tried the solutions from other posts but none of them worked for me. I have magento on godaddy ver. 1.9. 
I tried keys in several formats like:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/[name]

magento-community/[name]

http://connect20.magento-commerce.com/community/[name]

Godaddy , of course, is never helpful. Can anybody give me any suggestions to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

That first example should be correct and is a Connect 2.0 format key.  That's the format you want for Community 1.9.  It looks like your error comes from the 2nd example which isn't a hostname.  If you copy the installer key directly from Connect as-is on the product page it should work.  Alternatively you can use a tool like http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php to paste keys into and download an archive of the code so you can review the code and install manually.  This is a safer route because you can have a look at the code before it goes on your store.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this for a community-channel module:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Cardpay_Payeezy
```

with a space between the community url and the module name.

Handy to run inside a docker container as part of an init script.

Answer (score 1):

- **Solution**

Magento Connect  Unable to download Plugin [RESOLVED]
While installing Plugins from magento I came across

> Could not resolve host: magento-community

Could not resolve host: magento-community

**SOLUTION**

If you get the URL Key for the magento connect in the below format without http 
“ magento-community/contactsformcaptcha “

2)  Add the prefix URL  http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/
Followed by the Plugin name as shown below:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/contactsformcaptcha

> Kindly omit the magento-community to community

3) Paste the Url in the field “Paste extension key to install “ and you are good to download the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Use community/(Your Extension) when you could not resolve host magento-community